# grab text with [quote]foo text[/quote] and replace it to <div class="quote-text">foo text</div> with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey, I have some text that is formatted like this:

```
[quote]foo text[/quote]
```

and I want to change it to this:

```
<div class="quote-text">foo text</div>
```

How can I do this with JS?

I'm using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
string.replace(/\[quote\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/g, "<div class=\"quote-text\">".$1."</div>");
```

Comment: Probably better to use the non-greedy `.*?` in order to allow more than one quote in the text.

Comment: Thanks Dav, added that, and the g option. If you want to match [QUOTE]blahblah[/QUOTE] as well, add the i option

Answer (score 0):

```
var myString = "blah blah [quote]test[/quote] foo bar [quote]another thing[/quote]";

myString.replace(/\[quote\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/g, '<div class="quote-text">$1</div>');
```